# Mysql, replace entire column with another tables column

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table which needs to be replaced with a column from another table. Basically one is the short description of items and the other (that was found in another table) is the long descriptions of the same items in the same order.

I'm pretty new to actually writing queries with mysql, (i've always relied on ActiveRecord or the like), so please don't newbie bash me on that.

What would this query look like?

Comment: What are the columns in both tables, and what column(s) can be used to relate one table to the other?

Comment: It's just one column `items::short_description` and the other is in a different table `details::long_description`, since I don't need the short descriptions, and I'd rather not have a relationship for just the description I'd like to replace the `short_description` column in the `items` table 1-for-1 with the `long_description` column in the `details` table.

Comment: Without something to tie the records between the tables on a 1 to 1 ratio, the best you can do is a cartesian product (not good).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    FirstTable
    JOIN SecondTable ON FirstTable.ItemID = SecondTable.ItemID
SET
    FirstTable.Description = SecondTable.LongerDescription
```